# Use Jena to write JSON-LD

Tags: java, jena, json-ld

I have previously used Jena 2.11.0 and jsonld-java to serialize a Jena model to JSON-LD. In this case I needed to call

```
JenaJSONLD.init();
```

in order to use

```
OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
model.write(os, "JSON-LD");
```

which all worked out fine. Now I have updated to Jena 2.12.1 which is said to have native JSON-LD support. However, the code above then causes

*com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.NoWriterForLangException: JSON-LD*

What do I need to do in Jena 2.12 to get the same writer initialization as with 2.11 and jsonld-java? I have noticed that jsonld-java 0.5 is a dependency for jena-arq but not jena-core. I am not using arq so I have added jsonld-java to my project dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jena-arq.  The latest parsers also cover features like datasets which (for legacy reasons) exist in ARQ.

(How you got anything to work for 2.11.0 without jena-arq in the classpath is quite a surprise to me.)

Comment: Thanks! I even finally got it to work with Jena 2.12.1 and jsonld-java-jena 4.1. But, with jena-arq included will model.write(os, "JSON-LD"); work without further initialization?

Comment: 1/ Try it!  2/ Yes.  

Initialization is automatic (a good reason for moving it into Jena itself)